# How to perform lookaheads with string iterators?

Tags: string, rust, iterator

I want to try to get familiar with Rust, so I'm attempting [Crafting Interpreters](https://craftinginterpreters.com/). In the [Longer Lexemes](https://craftinginterpreters.com/scanning.html#longer-lexemes) section it has a `peek` function that gets the character one ahead of the current index.

I'm not sure how to go about this in Rust. It seems that indexing strings is discouraged due to the design of the language and complexities with Unicode.

If I do `chars.next()` then it will consume the value. I thought that `.as_bytes()` on the original string could work, but that only supports ASCII values. From the internet, `.chars().nth().unwrap()` is the solution, but it seems to be very slow.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable

Comment: @BallpointBen tysm

Comment: The chars iterator supports clone. You can clone it, then call next on the clone which won't consume the original.

Comment: Writing parsers in Rust using character iterators is awkward. It's a lot nicer to use the `regex` crate, a parser generator like `nom`, or to operate on bytes. But if you must, it helps that `Chars` is `Clone` and that it has an `.as_str()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A practical example of @BallpointBen's comment about using [`peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable) would be:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = "Hello, world!";
    let mut iter = data.chars().peekable();
    
    while let Some(&current) = iter.peek() {
        // Do something with the current character without consuming it
        println!("Current character: {}", current);

        // Now consume the character
        iter.next();
        
        // You can also peek the next character without consuming it
        if let Some(&next) = iter.peek() {
            println!("Next character: {}", next);
        } else {
            println!("This was the last character.");
        }
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20data%20%3D%20%22Hello%2C%20world%21%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20iter%20%3D%20data.chars%28%29.peekable%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20while%20let%20Some%28%26current%29%20%3D%20iter.peek%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Do%20something%20with%20the%20current%20character%20without%20consuming%20it%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println%21%28%22Current%20character%3A%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20current%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Now%20consume%20the%20character%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20iter.next%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20You%20can%20also%20peek%20the%20next%20character%20without%20consuming%20it%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20let%20Some%28%26next%29%20%3D%20iter.peek%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println%21%28%22Next%20character%3A%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20next%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println%21%28%22This%20was%20the%20last%20character.%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Output:

```
Current character: H
Next character: e
Current character: e
Next character: l
Current character: l
Next character: l
Current character: l
Next character: o
Current character: o
Next character: ,
Current character: ,
Next character:  
Current character:  
Next character: w
Current character: w
Next character: o
Current character: o
Next character: r
Current character: r
Next character: l
Current character: l
Next character: d
Current character: d
Next character: !
```